# Advert appearing twice - in some browsers not others

Tags: html

I have a small and simple pure HTML website [here](http://www.fullreservebanking.com), which contains an advert in a `table` on the left hand side of every page in the site. I only ever checked that it worked on Firefox on a PC. But just now I have been alerted to the fact that on the front page, the advert appears in two locations in both Chrome, Internet Explorer and Firefox for Mac. Even more strangely, the double-advert looks fine (i.e. just appears once) on every *other* page on the site, regardless of the browser - even though the code for the ad is identical.

I'm completely baffled.

Comment: Are you sure the code is identical on each page?  On the home page the 2nd image is being pulled from a different website: <img src="https://affiliates.europacbank.com/accounts/default1/banners/120x240.jpg"  />

On the inner pages, this code doesn't appear.

Comment: Wow! your comment led to me finding the problem - see edit to OP. Thank you.

Comment: @Zistoloen: ok done but I have to wait 21 hours to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I had a spurious secondary link to the image on the front page (now removed)... though how/why this never showed in Firefox for PC may remain a mystery forever!